# Как реализовать статистику посещений в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Ребят, всех приветствую.
В общем столкнулся с таким вопросом.

Упрощу несущественные нюансы. В базе есть таблица `statistic_visit`
Примерно с такой структурой: `id|visit|date`
То есть грубо говоря при каждом обновлении страницы, должен инкреметироваться `visit` где дата соответствует сегодняшней.

Зондируя просторы интернета и документаций, подумал что правильнее будет сделать через **Provider**:

```
class StatisticVisitProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(Request $request)
    {
        $toDay = date("Y-m-d");

        StatisticVisit::where('day', $toDay)->increment('view', 1);

    }

    public function register()
   {

   }
}
```

Все отрабатывает, но есть одна проблемка. В базу он при каждом обновлении плюсует не на 1, а на большее число, **например 3, 80**. Видимо зависимо от того какую страницу открываю.

И соответственно напрашивается вывод, что провайдер отрабатывает не один раз. То есть при каждом ajax запросе, или подгрузке какого либо виджета он отрабатывает инкремент.

Прошу подсказать, как правильно это реализовать, на верном ли я пути если нет то направить.

Заранее премного благодарен.

Comment: Я делал похожее в посреднике. Создал необходимый класс, добавил его в  массив `$routeMiddleware`  и после нужным мне роутам присвоил созданный посредник.

Comment: а может он увеличивает на количество найденных строк вашим запросом?

Comment: При большом потоке посетителей может отказать база данных в связи с нагрузкой, используйте технологии которые были для этого созданы, к примеру любые аналитические тулзы или сохранение логов на nginx/apache, в более продвинутых вариантах использование готовых решений по типу elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Этот вариант уже озвучивался в комментарии выше. Я бы тоже делал через middleware. 
По поводу того, что нужно разграничивать ajax и обычный клиентский синхронный http запрос тут есть несколько вариантов:

- использовать /api руты для ajax вызовов, а мониторить только все оставшиеся руты. (соответственно, к ним и применить middleware)
- проверять в middlrware тип запроса

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231587/laravel-check-if-ajax-request